# Is there a way to restrict the search within certain bounds in Google Maps API (latitude & longitud)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I'm trying to restrict a search results. I cannot use this method's class (google.maps.places.SearchBox)

```
setBounds(bounds:LatLngBounds|LatLngBoundsLiteral)
```

Because the results are not restricted to the bounds, but prioritized.

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and [MCVE]

Comment: you cannot restrict, only prioritise. You must take care of eliminating results you don't want by some other method depending on your criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the strict bounds are supported only in the Place autocomplete.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#AutocompleteOptions

The Search Box doesn't have this property

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#SearchBoxOptions

I would suggest filing a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188853&template=787814) to add strict bounds support in the Search Box class as well.